# How to store output using different unique key (tried CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to understand how I can convert what is currently stored in my sql tbl. The LBid is the unique ID and the productString column contains all of the product IDs that exist within each LBid. I need to write a statement to store each individual product ID (stored within productString) as the unique ID with all the associated LBids in a CSV format.

Current output

```
LBid    title   noProducts  productString
51631   Slide2      NULL    NULL
51636   Slide3      1       49518
51638   Slide4      1       49512
51641   Slide5      2       49512,49518
51643   Slide6      4       49512,46163,49518,46157
51645   Slide7      3       49874,47339,46165
51647   Slide8      5       49874,48807,49934,46766,47339
51649   Slide9      7       46165,48807,49874,47339,46766,47648,47948
```

Desired output

```
Product ID  LBid
49518       51636,51641,51643
49512       51638,51641,51643
etc...
```

I've tried using the following code which helps me to split out the productString column, but I don't know how to save the output from this SELECT statemnet.

```
SELECT value, LBid, title, noProducts, productString
FROM dbo.LB  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(productString, ',')

GROUP BY value, LBid, title, noProducts, productString
ORDER BY value;
```

Output from above statement (this is a sample, may not directly reflect above code)

```
value   id      title       productString
45891   52316   Slide337    45891,47205,47205,47209,47209,47443,47447,49246,47131,48744,48746
45909   52708   Slide533    47260,47248,49204,50783,48817,47270
45911   52708   Slide533    47260,47248
45917   51893   Slide129    45917,47910,46073,46077,50119,48813,45921,46729,46708,46706
45921   51893   Slide129    45917,47910,46073,46077,50119,48813,45921,46729,46708,46706
45923   51843   Slide104    50299,50132,50130,49548,49496,49577,45923,50060,46706
45923   51845   Slide105    45923,49577,50132,48923,46706,49747
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

SQL Azure / SMSS

Comment: I was a little confused. Do you want information from a table and do you want Desired output? Like the picture?

Comment: I would like the output from the desired output (if possible)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to write a statement to store each individual product ID (stored within productString) as the unique ID with all the associated LBids in a CSV format.

You need to aggregate:

```
SELECT lb.LBid, STRING_AGG(s.value, ',')
FROM dbo.LB CROSS APPLY
     STRING_SPLIT(lb.productString, ',') s
GROUP BY lb.LBid
ORDER BY lb.LBid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm not sure I quite understand how your aggregate code varies from mine? It produces the same output? Maybe I wasn't clear in my first request, I'm trying to group by lb.productString value (e.g. individual productString 45891, 47205, etc..) does that make sense?

Comment: @Pythonn00b . . . Look at the overall query, particularly the `GROUP BY`.